# Adding An item to sharepoint list using WCF service does not start workflow on that list

Tags: wcf, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-workflow

I tried adding a new item to list using WCF Service . The item is added successfully to the list but sharepoint 2013 designer workflow does not start on that list item, no workflows where created at all (the status column was empty).

(The workflow should start on item created)

I tried changing the WCF IIS application pool user not to be the system account but still the same issue happened.

Does the WCF require a special configuration to run the workflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by applying the following  :

1-  The user of the web service application pool (Identity) should not have an admin privilege and must only have the below rights :

```
Member of:
Domain users
IIS_Users
Performance log
Performance Monitor
SQLServerMSAS
WSS_WPG
WindowsFabricAL
```

2- The web.config of the web service must include the below parts under the configuration section (So that the web service can Identify the workflow and the items added by it cause the workflow to start): Hint : This part is taken of the web.config of the sharepoint site itself

```
 <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="System.Workflow.ComponentModel.WorkflowCompiler" type="System.Workflow.ComponentModel.Compiler.WorkflowCompilerConfigurationSectionGroup, System.Workflow.ComponentModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35">
      <section name="authorizedTypes" type="System.Workflow.ComponentModel.Compiler.AuthorizedTypesSectionHandler, System.Workflow.ComponentModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
      <section name="authorizedRuleTypes" type="System.Workflow.ComponentModel.Compiler.AuthorizedTypesSectionHandler, System.Workflow.ComponentModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <System.Workflow.ComponentModel.WorkflowCompiler>
    <authorizedTypes>
      <targetFx version="v4.0">
        <authorizedType Assembly="System.Workflow.Activities, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" Namespace="System.Workflow.*" TypeName="*" Authorized="True" />
        <authorizedType Assembly="System.Workflow.Activities, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" Namespace="System.Workflow.*" TypeName="WhileActivity" Authorized="False" />
        <authorizedType Assembly="System.Workflow.Activities, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" Namespace="System.Workflow.*" TypeName="ConditionedActivityGroup" Authorized="False" />
        <authorizedType Assembly="System.Workflow.Activities, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" Namespace="System.Workflow.*" TypeName="ReplicatorActivity" Authorized="False" />
        <authorizedType Assembly="System.Workflow.ComponentModel, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" Namespace="System.Workflow.*" TypeName="*" Authorized="True" />
        <authorizedType Assembly="System.Workflow.ComponentModel, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" Namespace="System.Workflow.*" TypeName="WorkflowCompiler" Authorized="False" />
        <authorizedType Assembly="System.Workflow.Runtime, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" Namespace="System.Workflow.Runtime" TypeName="CorrelationToken" Authorized="True" />
        <authorizedType Assembly="mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" Namespace="System" TypeName="Guid" Authorized="True" />
        <authorizedType Assembly="mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" Namespace="System" TypeName="DateTime" Authorized="True" />
        <authorizedType Assembly="mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" Namespace="System" TypeName="Boolean" Authorized="True" />
        <authorizedType Assembly="mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" Namespace="System" TypeName="Double" Authorized="True" />
        <authorizedType Assembly="mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" Namespace="System" TypeName="String" Authorized="True" />
        <authorizedType Assembly="mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" Namespace="System.Collections" TypeName="Hashtable" Authorized="True" />
        <authorizedType Assembly="mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" Namespace="System.Collections" TypeName="ArrayList" Authorized="True" />
        <authorizedType Assembly="mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" Namespace="System.Diagnostics" TypeName="DebuggableAttribute" Authorized="True" />
        <authorizedType Assembly="mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" Namespace="System.Runtime.CompilerServices" TypeName="CompilationRelaxationsAttribute" Authorized="True" />
        <authorizedType Assembly="mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" Namespace="System.Runtime.CompilerServices" TypeName="RuntimeCompatibilityAttribute" Authorized="True" />
        <authorizedType Assembly="mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" Namespace="System" TypeName="Int32" Authorized="True" />
        <authorizedType Assembly="mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" Namespace="System" TypeName="TimeSpan" Authorized="True" />
        <authorizedType Assembly="mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" Namespace="System.Collections.ObjectModel" TypeName="Collection`1" Authorized="True" />
        <authorizedType Assembly="System.Workflow.Activities, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" Namespace="System.Workflow.*" TypeName="*" Authorized="True" />
        <authorizedType Assembly="System.Workflow.Activities, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" Namespace="System.Workflow.*" TypeName="WhileActivity" Authorized="False" />
        <authorizedType Assembly="System.Workflow.Activities, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" Namespace="System.Workflow.*" TypeName="ConditionedActivityGroup" Authorized="False" />
       <authorizedType Assembly="System.Workflow.Activities, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" Namespace="System.Workflow.*" TypeName="ReplicatorActivity" Authorized="False" />
        <authorizedType Assembly="System.Workflow.ComponentModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" Namespace="System.Workflow.*" TypeName="*" Authorized="True" />
        <authorizedType Assembly="System.Workflow.ComponentModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" Namespace="System.Workflow.*" TypeName="WorkflowCompiler" Authorized="False" />
        <authorizedType Assembly="System.Workflow.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" Namespace="System.Workflow.Runtime" TypeName="CorrelationToken" Authorized="True" />
        <authorizedType Assembly="mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" Namespace="System" TypeName="Guid" Authorized="True" />
        <authorizedType Assembly="mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" Namespace="System" TypeName="DateTime" Authorized="True" />
        <authorizedType Assembly="mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" Namespace="System" TypeName="Boolean" Authorized="True" />
        <authorizedType Assembly="mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" Namespace="System" TypeName="Double" Authorized="True" />
        <authorizedType Assembly="mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" Namespace="System" TypeName="String" Authorized="True" />
        <authorizedType Assembly="mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" Namespace="System.Collections" TypeName="Hashtable" Authorized="True" />
        <authorizedType Assembly="mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" Namespace="System.Collections" TypeName="ArrayList" Authorized="True" />
        <authorizedType Assembly="mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" Namespace="System.Diagnostics" TypeName="DebuggableAttribute" Authorized="True" />
        <authorizedType Assembly="mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" Namespace="System.Runtime.CompilerServices" TypeName="CompilationRelaxationsAttribute" Authorized="True" />
        <authorizedType Assembly="mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" Namespace="System.Runtime.CompilerServices" TypeName="RuntimeCompatibilityAttribute" Authorized="True" />
        <authorizedType Assembly="mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" Namespace="System" TypeName="Int32" Authorized="True" />
        <authorizedType Assembly="mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" Namespace="System" TypeName="TimeSpan" Authorized="True" />
        <authorizedType Assembly="mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" Namespace="System.Collections.ObjectModel" TypeName="Collection`1" Authorized="True" />
        <authorizedType Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow" TypeName="SPWorkflowActivationProperties" Authorized="True" />
        <authorizedType Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow" TypeName="SPWorkflowTaskProperties" Authorized="True" />
        <authorizedType Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow" TypeName="SPWorkflowHistoryEventType" Authorized="True" />
        <authorizedType Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow" TypeName="SPItemKey" Authorized="True" />
        <authorizedType Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow" TypeName="SPWorkflowUserContext" Authorized="True" />
        <authorizedType Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowActions, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowActions" TypeName="*" Authorized="True" />
        <authorizedType Assembly="Microsoft.Office.Access.Server.Application, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" Namespace="Microsoft.Office.Access.Server.Macro.Runtime" TypeName="*" Authorized="True" />
        <authorizedType Assembly="Microsoft.Office.Access.Server.Application, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" Namespace="Microsoft.Office.Access.Server.Quickflow.Runtime" TypeName="*" Authorized="True" />
        <authorizedType Assembly="Microsoft.Office.Workflow.Actions, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" Namespace="Microsoft.Office.Workflow.Actions" TypeName="*" Authorized="True" />
      </targetFx>
    </authorizedTypes>
    <authorizedRuleTypes>
      <targetFx version="v4.0">
        <authorizedType Assembly="Microsoft.Office.Access.Server.Application, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" Namespace="Microsoft.Office.Access.Server.Quickflow.Runtime" TypeName="*" Authorized="True" />
        <authorizedType Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowActions, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowActions" TypeName="WorkflowCodeTypeReferenceExpression" Authorized="True" />
        <authorizedType Assembly="System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" Namespace="System.Runtime.CompilerServices" TypeName="ExtensionAttribute" Authorized="True" />
        <authorizedType Assembly="mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" Namespace="System.Runtime.CompilerServices" TypeName="ExtensionAttribute" Authorized="True" />
      </targetFx>
    </authorizedRuleTypes>
  </System.Workflow.ComponentModel.WorkflowCompiler>
```

3-  The user to add the items to the SharePoint list in the code should not have an identity as an administrator but must be as well a site owner.

4-  The code that add the items should not run with administrated privileges delegate.